# Getting the result of Iactionresult in .net Core using nswagger studio

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, nswagstudio

I have this api as you can see :

```
 [HttpGet("CreateToken")]

    public IActionResult CreateToken()
    {


        string tokenString = string.Empty;

        tokenString = BuildJWTToken();

        return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
    }
```

I use `nswagger studio` to generate my api code  as you can see in my MVC core

```
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateTokenAsync()
        {
            return CreateTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }

        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Default1/CreateToken");

            var client_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");

                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);

                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }

                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);

                        var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                        if (status_ == "200")
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                            throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response_ != null)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (client_ != null)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

This code is generated by NswaggerStudio .
So when I want to call my `createtoken` API as you can see i couldn't get the token in the result:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {

        var q = myapi.CreateTokenAsync();
        ViewBag.data = q;
        
        return View(q);
    }
```

And the view

```
<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">@ViewBag.data</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>
```

And here you can see the result

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ehsan Akbar,you call `CreateTokenAsync` method in your Index action,but this action does not return any value.

Comment: @Rena as you can see I have put the value into the viewbag

Comment: Hi @Ehsan Akbar,I know you put the value into the viewbag,but the value you put is not correct data because `myapi.CreateTokenAsync()` is a asynchronous method with no returning value.What does your CreateToken method use to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot return result in this way.

To return any model your returning type in method should look like something like this

```
[HttpGet("CreateToken")]
public IActionResult<TokenModel> CreateToken()
{
    string tokenString = string.Empty;
    tokenString = BuildJWTToken();
    return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
}
```

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#describe-response-types) for more information

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative solution to this with ProducesResponseType (part of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc).

Setting the typeof to the correct value you wish to return, will let swagger generate the json correctly. Which in turn allows nswag studio to generate

```
[HttpGet("CreateToken")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Token), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]

public IActionResult CreateToken()
{
    string tokenString = string.Empty;
    tokenString = BuildJWTToken();
    return Ok(new { Token = tokenString });
}
```